# Hazelcast for distributed cache in prod level java applications

Tags: java, hazelcast

We are developing a few java applications where we need to maintain distributed cache. Can I use Hazelcast for distributed cache.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, it actually is one of the most common use cases.